# Whitewashes the screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, screen, fedora

afrter reinstail my ubuntu 14.10 my laptop (Acer Aspite 5750G) begin whitewashes the screen when I start Ubuntu, I use double boot with Windows 8.1, I try to make another USB live Linux - Fedora, but in Fedora have some whitewashes problem, when mouse cursor move he whitewashes the screen.
I use Ubuntu 1 year, but never have this problem...
Alla distros of Linux now have this problem.